# How to fix firebase database initialised multiple times due to React SSR initialised database and cloud function firebase initialised database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have updated the question as found the root cause of the issue.
As I have hosted my React SSR app which uses firebase database in the client serving by one of the cloud function named `app` throwing an error of `Error: FIREBASE FATAL ERROR: Database initialized multiple times. Please make sure the format of the database URL matches with each database() call.`. When I comment out one by one and deploy, works perfectly. But when I deploy together doesn't work. How do I separate these two keeping both at the same repo?

ORIGINAL Question: `Why firebase cloud function throwing an error of 'The default Firebase app does not exist.'?`
So I am trying out firebase function for the first time. admin.messaging() throwing me the following error. Help me figure out why?
If I look at the console I get results till `console.log('deviceToken', deviceToken);`

so whats wrong in `const messageDone = await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(deviceToken, payload);`?

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
exports.updateUnreadCount = functions.database.ref('/chats/{chatId}/{messageId}')
  .onCreate(async(snap, context) => {
    const appOptions = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG);
    appOptions.databaseAuthVariableOverride = context.auth;
    const adminApp = admin.initializeApp(appOptions, 'app');
    const { message, senderId, receiverUid } = snap.val();
    console.log(message, senderId, receiverUid);
    console.log('------------------------');
    const deleteApp = () => adminApp.delete().catch(() => null);
    try {
      const db = adminApp.database();
      const reciverUserRef = await db.ref(`users/${receiverUid}/contacts/${senderId}/`);
      console.log('reciverUserRef', reciverUserRef);
      const deviceTokenSnapshot = await reciverUserRef.child('deviceToken').once('value');
      const deviceToken = await deviceTokenSnapshot.val();
      console.log('deviceToken', deviceToken);

      const payload = {
        notification: {
          title: 'Test Notification Title',
          body: message,
          sound: 'default',
          badge: '1'
        }
      };
      const messageDone = await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(deviceToken, payload);
      console.log('Successfully sent message: ', JSON.stringify(messageDone));
      return deleteApp().then(() => res);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('error', err);
      return deleteApp().then(() => Promise.reject(err));
    }
  });
```

Update1: According to this https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send_to_a_topic, `admin.messaging().sendToDevice(deviceToken, payload)` APIs are only available in the Admin Node.js SDK?
So switched to

```
const payload = {
        data: {
          title: 'Test Notification Title',
          body: message,
          sound: 'default',
          badge: '1'
        },
        token: deviceToken
      };
      const messageDone = await admin.messaging().send(payload);
```

Which is not working either. Getting an error `Error: The default Firebase app does not exist. Make sure you call initializeApp() before using any of the Firebase services.` Any lead will be helpful.

EDIT: Finally got the function working.
My index.js is exporting to functions, follwoing

```
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app); //React SSR
exports.updateChat = functions.database.ref('/chats/{chatId}/{messageId}').onCreate(updateChat);
```

`exports.app` is a react ssr function, which I am using to host my site. This uses database too. and throwing error of `multiple database instance`.
When I comment out one by one and deploy, works perfectly. But when I deploy together doesn't work. How do I separate these two keeping both at the same repo? Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Ok, no luck so far :(

Comment: you havent initialized the app like `admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
});` as given in [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server) so its unable to figure out the firebase project with which it is associated.

Comment: So `process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG` has the config too. I am initialized the admin using `const adminApp = admin.initializeApp(appOptions, 'app');`. Do you think it would make a difference if I initialize with `admin.initializeApp({ credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(), });`. I can try this option too.

Comment: It worked for me when initialising the way written in docs, also make sure you have exported file path like `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/user/Downloads/service-account-file.json"`

Comment: quick question, would it wise to keep the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in the repo? Cause I deploy my functions via CI pipeline.

Comment: repo definitely NO, since you are using CI using pipeline there will be a place where you can mention your project secrets like these.

Comment: Here's an update ` const admin = require('firebase-admin'); const serviceAccount = require('../../config/ownerstown-admin.json');admin.initializeApp({credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount), databaseURL: 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com' });/*const appOptions = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG);const adminApp = admin.initializeApp(appOptions, 'app');*/module.exports = {admin};` When I comment out my old config and try out the way you asked, throwing @firebase/database: FIREBASE FATAL ERROR: Database initialized multiple times.

Comment: Is there database url already mentioned in your serviceAccount file ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199409/discussion-between-subhendu-kundu-and-warl0ck).

Comment: So finally got it working after creating a new test project.
here's the difference between two folders,
working example has,
- index.js  // only one functions exports.updateTest = functions.database.ref('/chats/{chatId}/{messageId}').onCreate(updateUnreadCount);
-package.json
-firebase.json
-.firebaserc
Not working example only difference
-index.js //while it has two functions exporting
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);  //this is for hosting
exports.updateUnreadCount = functions.database.ref('/chats/{chatId}/{messageId}').onCreate(updateUnreadCount);
how do I fix this?

Comment: I guess, the other firebase function I am exporting as `exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);` which is SSR for my react app which also uses firebase database, thats creating the issue. Anyway, ignore that? or probably I need to create a structure so that it doesn't conflict with each other. Any suggestions?

Comment: yeah, that could be the reason for multiple initialization for firebase database

Comment: But how do I keep both of them in the project? Any suggestions.

Comment: since you are doing SSR, you can initialize the firebase database only on client side.

Comment: Hi, this is pretty late but were you able to figure out running both SSR and your API simultaneously without getting the `multiple database instance` error?

Answer (score 4):

You can initialise db outside export function.

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const adminApp = admin.initializeApp(appOptions, 'app')
//continue code
```

Update:

```js
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const adminApp = admin.initializeApp(options);
async function initialize(options, apps = 'app') {
    try {
      const defaultApp = adminApp.name
      if(defaultApp) { 
          const adminApp1 = admin.initializeApp(apps);
      }else {
        const adminApp1 = admin.initializeApp(options, apps);
      }
    }catch(err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }
```

Modify this snippet as per your need and try it out

It abstracts initialize of app in another function. Just call this function at appropriate place in your code.

Comment: So it's initialised in function just one time as exported.
But I have one more function named is `app`, which is rendering my react app. But firebase functions initialising my database which is being used in the react app as `if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(FirebaseConfig);
}

class Firebase {
  constructor() {
    this.database = firebase.database();
`

Comment: then you can make another export function as a wrapper around adminApp which does exactly the same (check if database with certain conditions exist) and return adminApp object itself to be used

Comment: Well yes, that's correct. But I don't know how to do that :-(

Comment: Interesting. Question, would you call the initialize function?
I was guessing, as I am initializing the db from the client as well as from the server, its creating the issue, would this fix the issue? Or we should add a check of if db is already initialized then dont pass the db parameter. Something like that?

Comment: why are you initialising db on both client and server. shouldn't you do all db CRUD at one side?
Yes it is supposed to fix the issue as long as all db connections are made through this function, not sure though if its called on client side as well

Comment: So basically lets I updating my list from my client directly. Which has my listeners as well. For that I needed to intilized the DB too right? Now in the server I am trying to add aggregation to keep a count of list added. And add it in the database in a different collection.

Comment: i am not sure if it is right approach. but anyways you just need to maintiain unique connection in server and different on each client for this. this function will do the trick

Comment: Let's say its not the right approach, how would you initialize for both at the same time?

Comment: i think instead of making db changes directly from client, you can send data to backend. Since based on this data backend also needs to process something. Based on single data entry point, changing db from both server and client is not a good idea.

Comment: Also have you tries this solution (It uses inbuilt functions itself)?

Comment: Yes, I did, didn't work out. It still throwing the same error. `Error: FIREBASE FATAL ERROR: Database initialized multiple times.`